# Multiple visual studio applications in a single solution

Tags: visual-studio

Where and why should I add other applications to a single solution?

```
What are the usages of adding multiple apps to a single solution?
```

I've searched a lot but I found no clear description about this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to create a dll that holds your application model (database model). You need to make an WPF application that can work with the model AND you need to create a website so users can also access the data without the wpf app. Since you work on the same model project you don't write the code 2 times but instead you write it 1 time and link the projects together in 1 solution.

Comment: thanx syner. is that the only usage of multi apps in a solution?

Comment: that is most of the usage,, But I also use it for code seperation,,  For instance: You have a big application and you are going to make an updater for it. Instead of wanting to update the entire application everytime you have a new version you just want to update a tiny bit of the application,, the part that is changed. If you seperate your code into multiple dll's (every class project generates a dll) then you can more easely update parts of your program. Then you just need to update the dll that has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Projects are useful if you are creating components that will be reused between multiple applications.

For example, you could create a `Utilities` library, which outputs a .dll containing extension methods and classes that you use regularly to save you having to write the same code multiple times.  You can then include that library in any further applications you create.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that a project doesn't need to be an app - projects can create libraries or other artifacts (installers, which I suppose are also apps).

However, even if another project is an application it may make sense to have it in the same solution since it might share dependencies with the other project - or it might simply make sense form an organizational or workflow sense (for example, it might simply be that when you're working on 'appfoo', you often have to do some work in 'appbar').